# 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a problem with migrating my table.

I have a users table that has a string id and the table was created before with SQL without a migration.

Later on, I created a table called surveys that has a foreign key to user_id with the following code .

```
hema::create('surveys', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('user_id',40);
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users') ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('gender');
            $table->string('age');
            $table->string('education');
            $table->string('proficiency');
            $table->string('behaviour');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

I am always getting the below error whenever I try to migrate it and I have no clue why is this happening.
The id in table users is varchar 40 and so is the user_id.

```
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `d0372341`.`surveys` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `surveys` add constraint `surveys_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade)

  at D:\xampp install\htdocs\game-db\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:692
    688▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    689▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    690▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    691▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 692▕             throw new QueryException(
    693▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    694▕             );
    695▕         }
    696▕     }
```

So if you can please help me with this I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you put the schema of your **user** table ?

Comment: CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `achievements` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `level` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `local_rank` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `money` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `slant` text DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `achievements` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `level` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `local_rank` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `money` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `slant` text DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

Comment: Did you create your `users` table manually or from **migrations** ? if it's by **migration**, please modify your post and put the schema of your `users` table. In order to better understand and be able to help you

Comment: it was created manually

Comment: Ok, so to eliminate an option : is your `users` table created when you start the `surveys` table migration?

Comment: the users table is already in the database since a long time

Comment: In your `users` table, verify that the collation of your `id` field is **utf8mb4_unicode_ci**. The error can sometimes be due to this

Comment: Thanks alot @Atika you really saved my life lots of love .....it is working now<3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I post the answer here to help others :
(ps. don't forget to mark this answer as the best answer)

In your `users` table, verify that the collation of your `id` field is **utf8mb4_unicode_ci**. The error can sometimes be due to this.

Answer (score 0):

Change `$table->string('user_id',40);` to `$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id)`

Or if you're using Laravel 8.x you can basically do

```
$table->foreignId("user_id")->constrained()->cascaseOnDelete();
```

Then run this command

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

Edit:

Make sure the primary key in your users table is string then update your User model

```
public $incrementing = false;
protected $keyType = 'string';
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#primary-keys

Comment: I need the id to be a string so I can't change it and running this line of code gives same error
```
$table->foreignId("user_id")->constrained()->cascaseOnDelete();
```

Comment: still the same problem persists